# Can I know which entry of a file is being modified?

Tags: java, watchservice

I am watching a directory(file) using Java WatchService api. I want to know which line or entry of a particular file has been modified recently.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to have the file's pre-modified contents in memory and compare them yourself.  The WatchService API isn't designed to tell you what changed inside the files/directories, only that **something** did change.

Comment: I know that WatchService API is not designed to tell what changed.Just want to know the best way to know the only entry modified.

Comment: This really depends on how you are using the data in the file.  For instance, if it is some properties file that has been previously read in by your program you can compare each property to see which ones may have changed.  What type of file are you using?  With more info I can give a better answer.

Comment: I am using a property file. On some event I am reloading all properties.
I don't want to do reload all properties but only one's which has changed.Is it possible to do so efficiently? If not then reloading all properties still make sense instead of comparing each and every property.